# Declaring 2nd queue with a default exchange produces an error

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Spring Boot 1.5.15

When I declare one queue, that queue is declared and sending/receiving works fine.
If I add a second (and subsequent) queues, an error is logged, queues get re-declared 5 times and finally the app fails to start up.

Spring Boot RabbitMQ configuration:

```
    @Configuration
    public class RabbitConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {

        @Autowired
        private ObjectMapper mapper;

        @Bean
        Queue crmAppealQueue(@Value("${app.queues.portalAppeal}") String queueName) {
            return new Queue(queueName, false);
        }

        @Bean
        Queue portalUserQueue(@Value("${app.queues.portalUser}") String queueName) {
            return new Queue(queueName, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
            registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(messageHandlerMethodFactory());
        }

        @Bean
        MessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory() {
            DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
            messageHandlerMethodFactory.setMessageConverter(consumerJackson2MessageConverter());
            return messageHandlerMethodFactory;
        }

        @Bean
        public MappingJackson2MessageConverter consumerJackson2MessageConverter() {
            return new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        }

        @Bean
        public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
            final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
            rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
            return rabbitTemplate;
        }

        @Bean
        public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
            return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper);
        }
}
```

Logs with errors:

```
2018-29-08 15:04:52,075  INFO (RabbitAdmin.java:566) - Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (portal.appeal) durable:false, auto-delete:false, exclusive:false. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
2018-29-08 15:04:52,075  INFO (RabbitAdmin.java:566) - Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (portal.user) durable:false, auto-delete:false, exclusive:false. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
2018-29-08 15:04:52,122 ERROR (CachingConnectionFactory.java:1327) - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'durable' for queue 'portal.user' in vhost '/': received 'false' but current is 'true', class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

If one queue declaration is commented, then the log shows that only one queue is declared and the app continues to boot (that is, that another queue isn't declared elsewhere)

```
2018-29-08 17:21:49,435  INFO (AbstractConnectionFactory.java:379) - Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#74ba4614:0/SimpleConnection@2a6c087d [delegate=amqp://precrm@192.168.82.177:5672/, localPort= 63501]
2018-29-08 17:21:49,435  INFO (RabbitAdmin.java:566) - Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (portal.appeal) durable:false, auto-delete:false, exclusive:false. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
2018-29-08 17:21:49,529  INFO (StartupInfoLogger.java:57) - Started PortalAppealMessageHandlerTest in 5.317 seconds (JVM running for 6.599)
```

Comment: The `portal.user` queue already exists with different settings as what you configured here (that is what the error message is telling you). You cannot redeclare a queue.

Comment: Agree, that is what the log msg suggests, but I double-checked it to ensure that this is not the case. Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was a stupid one (quite expectedly).

I assumed that a queue is created from scratch each time it is declared which was not the case given my configuration.

Actually it has existed with a different durability arg - exactly what an error msg was trying to tell me.

Solution: I deleted it using `AmqAdmin.deleteQueue()`